# vscode linting failing to provide result

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

- VS code 1.63.2 installed on Fedora 35 via MS repo (not flatpak).
- Python3.10 installed via Fedora 35 repo.
- python3-autopep8,black and python3-flake8 are installed via repo.

VS Code is using Python3.10, the Python and Pylance extensions are installed.

My settings.json has:

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/bin/python",
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "/usr/bin/autopep8-3",
    "python.linting.flake8Path": "/usr/bin/flake8-3.10",
    "python.formatting.blackPath": "/usr/bin/black"
}
```

I have selected to use the flake8 as the linter via crtl+shift+p.  When i run the linter though, nothing happens, no errors.  Thats when run on a file like the below (which should fail)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

msg = 'hello'

print msg
```

What am I doing wrong pls?